# Select columns from various tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, multiple-tables

I have a dynamic list of categories, which is retrieved from mySQL. When the user is clicking on a category, it loads images for that specific category from the DB. This is the function that does it:

```
function getImages($categoryID)
{
return json_encode(select("SELECT * FROM images WHERE categoryID=$categoryID"));
}
```

Now I also want to retrieve also the category name again from the "categories" table (to include the name of the selected category in other part of the page). I tried to do this:

```
function getImages($categoryID)
{
return json_encode(select(
        "SELECT categories.categoryName, images.imageFileName, images.imageHeader 
        FROM images JOIN categories 
        ON categories.categoryID = images.categoryID 
        WHERE categoryID=$categoryID"));
}
```

but that didn't work, now I don't even get the images.

How can it be done?

Comment: `WHERE categoryID ...`  is ambiguous. Try `WHERE categories.categoryID ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your WHERE clause, categoryID is ambiguous.

```
WHERE categoryID=$categoryID
```

Since you have two tables with categoryID, you need to identify which one the WHERE should be looking at.

```
WHERE categories.categoryID=$categoryID
```

To make life easier for yourself, you might want to consider aliasing your tables, like this:

```
SELECT c.categoryName, i.imageFileName, i.imageHeader 
FROM images i
JOIN categories c ON c.categoryID = i.categoryID 
WHERE c.categoryID=$categoryID
```

Also, which language are you developing in?  If this is a web app, you might want to consider escaping $categoryID to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, that worked, now I get the category name and the images!
I develop in PHP and JS. And yes, it is for the web. Though I don't think that the users will even see the $categoryID part - when they click the link they see a JS code, like that: javascript:getImages(4), where getImages is the function that calls for the API.php and API.php for the BusinessLogic.php, which holds my getImages() function, with the SELECT statement. But I'd sure like to know more about SQL injection, as I plan to make some comments fields as well...

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in the SQL query, categoryID is ambiguous. Try:

```
SELECT 
    categories.categoryName, 
    images.imageFileName, 
    images.imageHeader 
FROM 
    images 
JOIN 
    categories on categories.categoryID = images.categoryID 
WHERE 
    categories.categoryID=$categoryID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Rehashing what's already been said, try a left join so that images that aren't categorized don't get filtered out and use an escape such as the following:

```
$query = "SELECT c.categoryName, i.imageFileName, i.imageHeader 
  FROM images i
LEFT JOIN categories c
  ON c.categoryID = i.categoryID 
WHERE c.categoryID= " . intval($categoryID) . ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must qualify the field in your `WHERE`clause with a table name, i.e.

```
WHERE image.categoryID=$categoryID
```

The databse engine does not know which of the two categoryID fields you mean. If you run into problems like this again, you should test the query on the MySQL command line. There you get an error message, that is very helpful in fixing your error.